# Firebase not initializing in Javascript program

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a to-do list that allows you to add, remove, and strike off tasks. I developed the front-end for the program, and it does work, but I'm having some issues with the back-end. I have a Firebase Firestore that I'm using to store the data, but I'm having trouble initializing the Firebase in my code. The part I added into the code was this:
(The reason why the script tag is not closed is because I had more javascript below which I didn't paste here).

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDx6xuNnelTuWLQVoJQQ_13_q3u2kULpCE",
    authDomain: "tododatabase-8cc76.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "tododatabase-8cc76",
    storageBucket: "tododatabase-8cc76.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "342835299624",
    appId: "1:342835299624:web:2864e35382d74599ef7c1d",
    measurementId: "G-NVT04Z3FYN"
});
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
```

I do have the node modules. I keep getting this error,
Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

also, when this error comes, all the rest of my js code stops working.
Can someone please help me.

Comment: The error suggest that it's happening in the browser, so it's not backend

Comment: can you describe how you are using this code?

Which file are you importing it into?

Comment: i am inputting it into my index.js file

Comment: Yeah, I ran the original thing in google chrome, tried it in firefox but instead got
Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “firebase/app” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code...

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

...is trying to import those classes from node modules.   This method is meant to be used by some library to compile and package your javascript to be ran from the page.

This statement...

> The reason why the script tag is not closed is because I had more javascript below which I didn't paste here

...and the error...

> Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app"

Seem to indicate you are just running javascript in an html page.   Newer browsers support import modules, but it is trying to find a file on your website relative to the path where your html file is (or it's base is specified) and you don't have those.

I think you should probably use a CDN for this as in the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-app.js'
import { getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-firestore.js'
```